# Shortening the code

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, optimization

Is there any way to shorten this code? It works well, but there just has to be a way to make it look better.

```
#d=69+12*log(2)*(f/440)
#d is midi, f is frequency
import math
f=raw_input("Type the frequency to be converted to midi: ")
d=69+(12*math.log(float(f)/440))/(math.log(2))
d=round(d)
```

The upper part is the converter, and the lower area is the one that needs to be shortened up...

```
if d==127:
    print("G")
elif d==126:
    print("F#")
elif d==125:
    print("F")
elif d==124:
    print("E")
elif d==123:
    print("D#")
elif d==122:
    print("D")
elif d==121:
    print("C#")
elif d==120:
    print("C")
elif d==119:
    print("B")
elif d==118:
    print("A#")
elif d==117:
    print("A")
elif d==116:
    print("G#")
elif d==115:
    print("G")
elif d==114:
    print("F#")
elif d==113:
    print("F")
elif d==112:
    print("E")
elif d==111:
    print("D#")
elif d==110:
    print("D")
elif d==109:
    print("C#")
elif d==108:
    print("C")
elif d==107:
    print("B")
elif d==106:
    print("A#")
elif d==105:
    print("A")
elif d==104:
    print("G#")
elif d==103:
    print("G")
elif d==102:
    print("F#")
elif d==101:
    print("F")
elif d==100:
    print("E")
elif d==99:
    print("D#")
elif d==98:
    print("D")
elif d==97:
    print("C#")
elif d==96:
    print("C")
elif d==95:
    print("B")
elif d==94:
    print("A#")
elif d==93:
    print("A")
elif d==92:
    print("G#")
elif d==91:
    print("G")
elif d==90:
    print("F#")
elif d==89:
    print("F")
elif d==88:
    print("E")
elif d==87:
    print("D#")
elif d==86:
    print("D")
elif d==85:
    print("C#")
elif d==84:
    print("C")
elif d==83:
    print("B")
elif d==82:
    print("A#")
elif d==81:
    print("A")
elif d==80:
    print("G#")
elif d==79:
    print("G")
elif d==78:
    print("F#")
elif d==77:
    print("F")
elif d==76:
    print("E")
elif d==75:
    print("D#")
elif d==74:
    print("D")
elif d==73:
    print("C#")
elif d==72:
    print("C")
elif d==71:
    print("B")
elif d==70:
    print("A#")
elif d==69:
    print("A")
elif d==68:
    print("G#")
elif d==67:
    print("G")
elif d==66:
    print("F#")
elif d==65:
    print("F")
elif d==64:
    print("E")
elif d==63:
    print("D#")
elif d==62:
    print("D")
elif d==61:
    print("C#")
elif d==60:
    print("C")
elif d==59:
    print("B")
elif d==58:
    print("A#")
elif d==57:
    print("A")
elif d==56:
    print("G#")
elif d==55:
    print("G")
elif d==54:
    print("F#")
elif d==53:
    print("F")
elif d==52:
    print("E")
elif d==51:
    print("D#")
elif d==50:
    print("D")
elif d==49:
    print("C#")
elif d==48:
    print("C")
elif d==47:
    print("B")
elif d==46:
    print("A#")
elif d==45:
    print("A")
elif d==44:
    print("G#")
elif d==43:
    print("G")
elif d==42:
    print("F#")
elif d==41:
    print("F")
elif d==40:
    print("E")
elif d==39:
    print("D#")
elif d==38:
    print("D")
elif d==37:
    print("C#")
elif d==36:
    print("C")
elif d==35:
    print("B")
elif d==34:
    print("A#")
elif d==33:
    print("A")
elif d==32:
    print("G#")
elif d==31:
    print("G")
elif d==30:
    print("F#")
elif d==29:
    print("F")
elif d==28:
    print("E")
elif d==27:
    print("D#")
elif d==26:
    print("D")
elif d==25:
    print("C#")
elif d==24:
    print("C")
elif d==23:
    print("B")
elif d==22:
    print("A#")
elif d==21:
    print("A")
elif d==20:
    print("G#")
elif d==19:
    print("G")
elif d==18:
    print("F#")
elif d==17:
    print("F")
elif d==16:
    print("E")
elif d==15:
    print("D#")
elif d==14:
    print("D")
elif d==13:
    print("C#")
elif d==12:
    print("C")
elif d==11:
    print("B")
elif d==10:
    print("A#")
elif d==9:
    print("A")
elif d==8:
    print("G#")
elif d==7:
    print("G")
elif d==6:
    print("F#")
elif d==5:
    print("F")
elif d==4:
    print("E")
elif d==3:
    print("D#")
elif d==2:
    print("D")
elif d==1:
    print("C#")
elif d==0:
    print("C")
```

Comment: use a mapping, such as an array or hashtable

Comment: If the code if working you should ask this at another site of the stack exchange web, named [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sorry about that @davejal I didn't realize I wasn't allowed to submit questions about the formatting of the code. thanks for the reference :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're checking an integer from 0 to 127, a `list` or `tuple` would be perfect, as you can simply access it with indexing:

```
>>> l = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'C', 'C#', 'D']
>>> d = 1
>>> print(l[d])
C#
```

On top of that, since the pattern repeats, you can use the `%` operator to divide and get the remainder, which will allow you to use a single cycle of the `list` or `tuple`:

```
>>> l = ['C', 'C#', 'D']
>>> d = 5
>>> print(l[d%3])
D
```

Use `d%12` instead of `d%3` for your case, as that's how many items you have.

Since you're using Python 2, judging by the use of `raw_input()` and the behavior of `round()`, you'll need to cast `d` to an integer with `d = int(round(d))` before using it as an index.

Be careful with those `print` statements, as adding parentheses doesn't turn it into something like Python 3's `print()` function. If you do something like `print('hello', 'world')` you'd get `('hello', 'world')` instead of the `'hello world'` you would see in Python 3 (or in Python 2 with the `print()` function imported).

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but whenever i try to use the list, I get an output of "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float"

Comment: @SpencerChurchill: **1)** use `int(index)` to turn the `index` into an integer, and **2)** use `d % len(lst)` instead of hard-coding the length (i.e. `d % 3`) as it will come back to bite you (as a bug) if you add/remove entries to/from it.

Comment: @SpencerChurchill - Sorry; I saw the parentheses with the `print` statements and thought you were using Python 3, but didn't notice the `raw_input()` that indicates Python 2. In Python 2, `round()` returns a `float`, while it returns an `int` in Python 3 when you round to zero decimal places.

Comment: Yay it works now! Thanks a ton! The program went from 262 lines to 8 lines! XD

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to notice is that the values are cyclical, they repeat every 12 steps (the number of halftones in an octave). You can find the position within the cycle using the modulus operator `%`. Then you just have 12 tests to perform.

But that can be simplified by using an array, where each array index corresponds to a note.

```
notes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
d_in_octave = d % 12;
print notes[d_in_octave]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list

```
notes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G"]

print notes[d]
```

Using a list and modular arithmetic:

```
notes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
print notes[d % len(notes)]
```